# Visual Studio Emulator for Android and NAT

Tags: android, visual-studio-2015, hyper-v, nat

I've got host PC behind NAT.  Thus, to make Internet connection from Hyper-V guest Linux OS, I have to:

1. In Hyper-V Virtual Switch Manager: create External Virtual Network Switch.
2. In Hyper-V Virtual Switch Manager: create Internal Virtual Network Switch.
3. In Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections -> External Virtual Network Switch -> Properties -> Sharing: enable Allow other network users to connect through this computer's Internet connection.
4. In Hyper-V Manager: configure the guest Linux OS to use Internal Virtual Network Switch.

Now, let's remove those switches and start from scratch.  When Visual Studio Emulator for Android is run, it creates new External Virtual Network Switch and new Internal Virtual Network Switch and both switches are used by this virtual machine.

Those two new switches don't have the sharing dependency as the previous ones.  Instead - I guess - the Internal Virtual Network Switch is used for interaction between guest OS and emulator running on host OS.  And External Virtual Network Switch is used for connecting the guest OS with Internet.  But the Internet connection doesn't work behind NAT.

How can I modify or add new switches to give Internet connection to guest Android machine?

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the external switch with a NAT internal switch should reduce some of the complexity here.  Visual studio may continue needing it's own network but replacing the external network with NAT may fix your issue.
  Here are [instructions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyperv_on_windows/user_guide/setup_nat_network).

Full disclosure:  I haven't tried that specific setup.